# MySQL fetching rows based on condition within condition

Tags: mysql

I have the following below

```
 ---------------------------------
 |   Id       |  Value    | Flag |
 ---------------------------------
 |   1        |   23      |  0   |
 ---------------------------------
 |   1        |   24      |  1   |
 ---------------------------------
 |   2        |   30      |  0   |
 ---------------------------------
```

I require a query, which should fetch the last two rows. The condition here is IF two rows have the same Id then the output should fetch the row which has flag = 1 . Where as If there is only one row for an Id, then the row with Flag = 0 should be fetched. Thus the output for the given requirement will be

```
 ---------------------------------
 |   1     |   24        |   1   |
 ---------------------------------
 |   2     |   30        |   0   |
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers looks correct to me. This is a different approach:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM
  yourtable t1 LEFT JOIN yourtable t2
  ON t1.Id = t2.Id AND t1.Flag=0 AND t2.Flag=1
WHERE
  t2.Id IS NULL
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95804/3).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
*
FROM yourTable yt1
WHERE Flag = (SELECT MAX(Flag) FROM yourTable yt2 WHERE yt1.Id = yt2.Id)
GROUP BY Id
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer an uncorellated approach...

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT id,MAX(flag) max_flag FROM my_table GROUP BY id ) y 
    ON y.id = x.id 
   AND y.max_flag = x.flag;
```